# PHP Guzzle Sending 2 requests on same time

Tags: php, web-services, token, guzzle

I'm trying to make 2 api calls at the same time, the first gets a token and the second brings the user data.

The problem is that when i pass the token on the second api call it gives me a session expired.

```
    $client = new Client([
        'base_uri' => 'https://portaldoagente.com.br/WCF/wcfTravellink/Loja.svc/', 
        'headers' => [
            'Content-Type' => 'application/json'
            ]
        ]);
```

**First call:**

```
    $response = $client->post('Autenticar',
        ['body' => json_encode(
            [
                'login' => 'example',
                'senha' => 'example'
            ]
        )],
    );
        $body = $response->getBody()->getContents();
        $responseXml = simplexml_load_string($body);

        $token = $responseXml->children;


        $response = $client->post('ConsultarCliente',
            ['body' => json_encode(
                [
                    'token'=> $token,
                    'ClienteLogin' => [
                        'Login' => 'example',
                        'Senha' => 'example'
                    ]
                ]
            )]
        );

        $Consulta = $response->getBody()->getContents();
```

The token needed to stay in the session so it would not expire?
When I try this in postman it works fine, first I make a call to the first method to get the token, then I make another call to the second method passing the token.